# How to set up Ignite node from Scala application for IgniteSet?

Tags: scala, ignite

I want to set up **[IgniteSet](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/data-structures/queue-and-set)** and fill it in Scala application using standalone Ignite cluster.

**What I am doing:** I raise client\server node, connect it to cluster and use Ignite instance to set up Set as shown in docs above. Similar to what I do for usual Ignite caches.

**What's the problem:** node cannot connect to cluster :(

**From application the error is:**

```
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start SPI: TcpDiscoverySpi [addrRslvr=null, sockTimeout=5000, ackTimeout=5000, marsh=JdkMarshaller [clsFilter=org.apache.ignite.marshaller.MarshallerUtils$1@32f308c6], reconCnt=10, reconDelay=2000, maxAckTimeout=600000, soLinger=0, forceSrvMode=false, clientReconnectDisabled=false, internalLsnr=null, skipAddrsRandomization=false]
...
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to deserialize object with given class loader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2c13da15
```

**From Ignite cluster the error is:**

```
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: javax.cache.configuration.MutableConfiguration; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 201405, local class serialVersionUID = 201306200821
```

`javax.cache.configuration.MutableConfiguration` is part of [`javax.cache.cache-api`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/javax.cache/cache-api) package and so the error says that there is some version mismatch. But I explicitly checked that my Ignite cluster uses 1.0.0 version - there is file `apache-ignite-2.9.1-bin/libs/cache-api-1.0.0.jar` in my `IGNITE_HOME`; and that my app uses the same version - in `build.sbt` I explicitly set (also tried to exclude this package at all):

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  ...,
  "javax.cache" % "cache-api" % "1.0.0"
)
```

Moreover I cannot find version of `javax.cache.cache-api` that uses such `serialVersionUID`: both 1.0.0 and 1.1.0 have `public static final long serialVersionUID = 201306200821L;`

**What I do in Scala application:**

```scala
# fails
# port == TcpDiscoverySpi port from cluster configuration
val host = "localhost:45900..46000" # also tried with single port and 

val tcpDiscoverySpi: TcpDiscoverySpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi
val ipFinder: TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder = new TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder
ipFinder.setAddresses(util.Arrays.asList(host.split(","): _*))
tcpDiscoverySpi.setIpFinder(ipFinder)

val igniteConfiguration: IgniteConfiguration = new IgniteConfiguration
igniteConfiguration.setDiscoverySpi(tcpDiscoverySpi)
igniteConfiguration.setClientMode(false) # also tried with true

val ignite: Ignite = Ignition.start(igniteConfiguration) # error raised here
```

*Also code snippet above works as expected from Java Spring application where the node is raised to set up Spring Data caches.*

What works as expected from Scala application is the connector node to Ignite cluster (for creating regular caches) but I cannot use it because it is not possible to set up `IgniteSet` with `IgniteClient` instance :(

```scala
# works as expected
val host = "localhost"
val connector_port = "10800" # == ClientConnectorConfiguration port from cluster configuration

val cfg = new ClientConfiguration()
      .setAddresses(host + ":" + connector_port)

val ignite: IgniteClient = Ignition.startClient(cfg)

val cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(...)
```

**What I do with Ignite cluster:** it is raised locally with script `bin/ignite.sh` of 2.9.1 version and with the following configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">

        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="localPort" value="45900"/>
                <property name="localPortRange" value="100"/>

                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.sharedfs.TcpDiscoverySharedFsIpFinder">
                        <property name="path" value="/opt/storage/ignite"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>


        <property name="communicationSpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi">
                <property name="localPort" value="47100"/>
            </bean>
        </property>


        <property name="clientConnectorConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.ClientConnectorConfiguration">
                <property name="port" value="10800"/>
                <property name="portRange" value="100"/>
            </bean>
        </property>


        <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
                <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                        <property name="maxSize" value="1073741824"/>
                        <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>

                <property name="storagePath" value="/opt/storage/ignite"/>
                <property name="walSegmentSize" value="134217728"/>

            </bean>
        </property>

    </bean>

</beans>
```

I am also able to connect to it by JDBC (`jdbc:ignite:thin://localhost:10800`), see it in DataGrip and store data both from Java app and Spark Streaming Dataframes.

So the questions are:

1. How to fix the problem - raise node from Scala app? Or maybe there is another valid way to create `IgniteSet`?
2. How to understand which type of nodes to raise for different tasks - access cache, create cache, create sets/queues, access sets/queues? There are thin nodes, thick nodes, among them client/server nodes...

Will be glad to any help!

**UPD:** found similar problem [here](http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Iginte-Exception-Failed-to-unmarshal-discovery-data-for-component-1-on-starting-server-from-console-E-tp8160p8239.html) - advice to exclude Geronimo JCache spec which `MutableConfiguration` [has serial number of `201405L`](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/geronimo/specs/tags/geronimo-jcache_1.0_spec-1.0-alpha-1/src/main/java/javax/cache/configuration/MutableConfiguration.java?view=co). I tried to exclude it but still have the same error:

```
excludeDependencies ++= Seq(
  ExclusionRule("org.apache.geronimo.specs"),
  ExclusionRule("org.apache.geronimo")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Apache Ignite needs JCache 1.0 and ships with corresponding version JAR.

If you have a different JAR in your client app compared to your server nodes, you may see this (de)serialization problem. You may use 1.1 or 1.0 but it has to match.

Comment: Thanks for reply! As I can see in Maven [`ignite-core`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ignite/ignite-core/2.9.1) depends on `javax.cache:cache-api:1.0.0` not 1.1. Moreover I explicitly set 1.0.0 version in my application and in Idea I can see 1.0.0 jar in dependencies.

Comment: I guess you are correct. Apache Ignite can use 1.1 or 1.0, but it needs to be the same version on all nodes in cluster.